# How to Read a File which is in another directory in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am a node.js developer first time learning and woking on an Android Project. I have requirement where i need to read .apk file from Build folder and push it to cloud api.

My `.apk` lives in `project-name/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/name-app-debug.apk`

I need call it or use it from `project-name/app/androidTest/java/com.name.app.name/testUtils`

If it's node.js i would have done something like `const filePath = path.resolve(process.cwd() + '/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/name-app-debug.apk');`

But it's so hard to do the same in the Kotlin or find a solution online.

```
testUtils.kt

class TestUtils { 
val file = File("path/to/file")
}
```

how to get the `path/to/file` for apk file which lives in `app/build/outputs/apk/debug/name-app-debug.apk` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a relative path, if i'm not wrong:

> "../../../build/outputs/apk/debug/name-app-debug.apk"

I never used Kotlin so maybe you want to know a specific way of getting via absolute path, but normally relative pathing should work.

Though it doesn't take much googling to discover how to do it, in the official documentation:

[Absolute pathing Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/absolute-path-string.html)